# How can I configure a "script" search path in WinDbg?

Tags: windbg

## Is there a script search path?

I want to use JavaScript (via jsprovider.dll) in WinDbg (well, really CDB). It seems that I either have to put my scripts in the directory I'm launching the debugger from or include complete paths to the scripts when I invoke the debugger. Are there alternatives?

- Is there any sort of script search path?
- Can you save a path (dirname) in a variable and use that with `.scriptload`?
- Is there a way that a script can know where it is? *(I have my scripts in version control software, so they're liable to be any number of places, not something I want to hardcode.)*

  - I'd like to have scripts "include" other scripts.

I have attempted each of these things without success. The [Javascript Debugger Scripting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/javascript-debugger-scripting) doc-point does not answer my questions directly.

### .scriptload FAIL

[.scriptload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-scriptload--load-script-) says

> Absolute or relative paths can be used. Relative paths are relative to the directory that you started the debugger in. File paths containing spaces are not supported.

It doesn't list options or alternatives.

I have tried using "variables" without success. Can you store a non-numeric value in a "variable"? I have ugly attempts that I could copy/paste here, but I was only guessing at syntax, so that probably isn't helpful.

### Partial, but Ugly Success

The only means of accomplishing what I want that I have found is to wrap the debugger script in a cmd script and have it use `%~dp0` to construct absolute paths to all the script files I want to load.

```
cdb.exe -c ".load jsprovider.dll;.scriptload %~dps0mylib.js;.scriptload %~dps0this_script.js;$<%~dp0this_script.scr" MyApp /arg1 /arg2
```

I would ordinarily prefer to load jsprovider and the scripts inside the '.scr' (windbg script), but I don't know how to get any environment info (dirs, etc) in there.

*Is there a better way?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either open a command prompt and set a temporary environment variable

or use MyComputer Properties and set a permanent Environment variable and use that inside windbg / cdb /kd

shown below is a temp env var usage

```
C:\>set w
windir=C:\Windows

C:\>set WINDBG_SCRIPT_DIR=f:\zzzz\wdscript

C:\>set w
WINDBG_SCRIPT_DIR=f:\zzzz\wdscript
windir=C:\Windows

C:\>cdb cdb

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 AMD64

(1d9c.231c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ff9`cb042dbc cc              int     3

0:000> as /e foo WINDBG_SCRIPT_DIR

0:000> al
  Alias            Value
 -------          -------
 foo              f:\zzzz\wdscript

0:000> .scriptload  ${foo}\mojo.js
JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'f:\zzzz\wdscript\mojo.js'
0:000> dx @$scriptContents.hola_mojo()
hola mojo this is javascript
```

Comment: [Aliases!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/as--as--set-alias-) Where have you been hiding in the WinDbg documentation?